# parsing logic proving very complex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that i must parse, setting a classes vars correctly from it. The string is badly structured but i can not change it. I have tried parsing it but dont have a good way to do it without issue. The string itself is a set of attributes and params that are used to trigger a exe from cmd line.

I have laid it out in a way to make easier to read but know that is it 1 continuous string.

Here are the rules as to how to read this line.
For every 'non -dll' command you can expect a single key and value pair. for the dlls lines you can have a single or multiple key-value pairs after the initial dll=,' ie the 'dll' element contains 0 or more keyValue or stand alone value split by spaces. eg 
dll=oneMoreDll, andItsParam=value anotherParam=value lastParam=value value

**Input string**

> time=value1 size=value2 dll=aDllName dll=anotherDllName, someParam=ParamValue  dll=yetAnotherDll, someOhterParam=anotherParamValue aStandAloneValue dll=oneMoreDll, andItsParam=value anotherParam=value lastParam=value

I want to be able to parse this string into the following format, i was thinking each line in a string array.

I have tried splitting by spaces and then 'dll' but my regex aint up to scratch or its impossible (im sure its not). Help!

**Desired output elements, to be stored in a String array**

```
time=value1 
size=value2 
dll=aDllName 
dll=anotherDllName, someParam=ParamValue  
dll=yetAnotherDll, someOhterParam=anotherParamValue aStandAloneValue
dll=oneMoreDll, andItsParam=value anotherParam=value lastParam=value
```

Comment: Why not split by spaces, and then further split the result by `=` ?

Comment: splitting by spaces leads to fragmenting of the dll strings with spaces in them, i want to keep each dlls detail together - some have params some dont

Comment: What is your question? Show expected input and output and **explain it**. **Why** do `dll=anotherDllName, someParam=ParamValue` belong together, `andItsParam=value anotherParam=value lastParam=value` also, but `attribute1=value1` and `attribute2=value2` not?

Comment: Split with [`Regex.Split(input, @"(?=\b(?:attribute\d+|dll)=)");`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3d%5cb(%3f%3aattribute%5cd%2b%7cdll)%3d)&i=attribute1%3dvalue1+attribute2%3dvalue2+dll%3daDllName+dll%3danotherDllName%2c+someParam%3dParamValue+dll%3dyetAnotherDll%2c+someOhterParam%3danotherParamValue+aStandAloneValue+dll%3doneMoreDll%2c+andItsParam%3dvalue+anotherParam%3dvalue+lastParam%3dvalue) - is that what you need? See the *Split* tab at the bottom.

Comment: I have stated the input and output. The attribute 1 and 2 dont belong together for reasons in the logic of the code, not relevant as i can not change this string and how it is used. i can give you a example string but its values will not add to the problem statement, the input and output as stated is sufficient i feel. Hold just a sec and il get you example

Comment: Except we would have seen dll names could have spaces in them

Comment: Hi Wikto Stribizew, im not sure but that sure looks a more complete solution than i was attemting in regex :)

Comment: I already had input and output in Q but i have now marked them clearly

Comment: PaulF - i mean dll elements have spaces in them, not the names themselves. Look at the desired output - can you achieve this?

Comment: _"The attribute 1 and 2 dont belong together for reasons in the logic of the code, not relevant"_ - it's very relevant, as this is required for a proper solution. Look, it can be as easy as writing a couple of sentences, like _"The string contains zero or more `attribute=value` pairs, followed by zero or more `dll=some_dll_name[, with some optional=attributevalues]`"_.

Comment: Im not sure what i can say, the desired output is stated, I have changed the 'attribute1' and 'attribute2' to random words 'time' and 'size' but again they are distinct values used by the cmd for purposes i cant influence. they have no bearing on each other hence must be separated as shown

Comment: My question is whether you can write down, in your question, in human language, what determines an attribute and a "dll line". For example after the first `dll=`, is it valid to have more random `attribute=value` "lines"? Is it valid for a "dll parameter" to have the format `dll=`?

Comment: Ok i will do that, apologies

Comment: Ok done. For every 'non -dll' command you can expect a single key and value pair. for the dlls lines you can have a single or multiple key-value pairs after the initial dll=,' ie the 'dll' element contains 0 or more keyValue or stand alone value split by spaces. eg dll=oneMoreDll, andItsParam=value anotherParam=value lastParam=value value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work, at least for the sample case.

1. Split the string by ' '
2. Split each sub-string by '='. If there's no '=', we simply take the left side.

We're now left with a structure that looks something like this:

`{ left = attribute1, right = value1 }, { left = attribute2, right = value2 }, { left = aStandAloneValue }`, etc.

Now, we need to group each item by the previous 'dll'. I'm using an extension method taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4682163/563532) to help with that.

Essentially, it will group until the condition is *not* met. In our case, we want to stop grouping when we hit a 'dll' entry. Or, if we haven't yet hit a 'dll' entry, then we always create a new group.

The rest is simply formatting the output (which may not be needed in your case).

```
var inStr = "time=value1 size=value2 dll=aDllName dll=anotherDllName, someParam=ParamValue dll=yetAnotherDll, someOhterParam=anotherParamValue aStandAloneValue dll=oneMoreDll, andItsParam=value anotherParam=value lastParam=value";

bool isBeforeAnyDll = true;

var result = inStr.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(r => {
        var split = r.Split('=');
        if (split.Length == 1)
            return new { left = split[0], right = (string)null };

        var left = split[0];
        var right = split[1];
        return new { left, right };
    })
    .GroupAdjacentBy((l, r) =>  {
        return r.left == "dll" 
             ? isBeforeAnyDll = false
             : !isBeforeAnyDll;
    })
    .Select(g => string.Join(" ", 
        g.Select(gg => { 
            if (gg.right == null)
                return gg.left;
            return string.Format("{0}={1}", gg.left, gg.right);
        })));


//https://stackoverflow.com/a/4682163/563532
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupAdjacentBy<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
    {
        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (e.MoveNext())
            {
                var list = new List<T> { e.Current };
                var pred = e.Current;
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (predicate(pred, e.Current))
                    {
                        list.Add(e.Current);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        yield return list;
                        list = new List<T> { e.Current };
                    }
                    pred = e.Current;
                }
                yield return list;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
time=value1 
size=value2 
dll=aDllName 
dll=anotherDllName, someParam=ParamValue 
dll=yetAnotherDll, someOhterParam=anotherParamValue aStandAloneValue 
dll=oneMoreDll, andItsParam=value anotherParam=value lastParam=value
```

The data is all properly grouped together after the `.GroupAdjacentBy()`, the following code is simply formatting the output.

Comment: Can you explain the _logic_ this code implements, so as to help OP verify whether it does what they want and so later visitors who stumble upon this can understand it?

Comment: Wow, thats brill....nearly there, just tested and my code spits out the 'dll' stuff on their correct lines aut doesnt separate the time and size, they appear in a continuous line. I can take it from here if you prefer, just thought i'd let you know

Comment: @Fearghal I've updated it since you've tested, it now will put time & size on separate lines :)

Comment: One more thing, how can we output a String[] instead of a IEEnum var?

Comment: @Fearghal Simply tack on a `.ToArray()` at the very end

Comment: mixed emotions. this is a great answer and does the job i stated however i have put my entire real life string in and it ends up not splitting correctly. my bad i guies, for some reason theres a diff even tho i cant see it

Answer (score 0):

Why not split by `Enviroment.NewLine` then by `,` then split by the first `=` sign, take the left part as the variable name, then the right part as the variable value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex approach using `Regex.Matches`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var log = "time=value1 size=value2 dll=aDllName dll=anotherDllName, someParam=ParamValue dll=yetAnotherDll, someOhterParam=anotherParamValue aStandAloneValue dll=oneMoreDll, andItsParam=value anotherParam=value lastParam=value";
        var res = Regex.Matches(log, @"\bdll=(?:(?!\bdll=).)*|\w+=\w+")
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(p => p.Value)
                 .ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n",res));
    }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/qRBjbB) and a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbdll%3d(%3f%3a(%3f!%5cbdll%3d).)*%7c%5cw%2b%3d%5cw%2b&i=time%3dvalue1+size%3dvalue2+dll%3daDllName+dll%3danotherDllName%2c+someParam%3dParamValue+dll%3dyetAnotherDll%2c+someOhterParam%3danotherParamValue+aStandAloneValue+dll%3doneMoreDll%2c+andItsParam%3dvalue+anotherParam%3dvalue+lastParam%3dvalue)

The regex matches 2 alternatives:

- `\bdll=` - a whole word `dll=` followed with...
- `(?:(?!\bdll=).)*` - zero or more characters that are not `dll`
- `|` - or....
- `\w+=\w+` - one or more word characters followed with `=` followed with one or more word characters.

Comment: Sorry Wiktor, in my effort to simplify i have given you a lever which really isn't avail, I updated the Q with a more realistic value - instead of attribute and 2 i mean i have a random string eg 'time' or 'egg' or 'salad'