# Linq - Group then compare elements within each group

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Suppose, for example, in my C# code, I have `MyClass`, defined as:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string GroupName;
    public DateTime Dt;
    public int Id;
    public string Val;
    .... other properties ....
}
```

And suppose I had the following `List<MyClass>` (showing it as a table since it seems the easiest way to describe the contents):

```
GroupName:       Dt:             Id:        Val:
Group1           2016/01/01      1          Val1
Group1           2016/01/02      1          Val1
Group1           2016/01/03      1          Val1
Group1           2016/01/04      1          Val2
Group1           2016/01/05      1          Val3
Group1           2016/01/06      1          Val1
Group1           2016/01/07      1          Val1
Group1           2016/01/08      1          Val4
Group1           2016/01/09      1          Val4
```

With, obviously, the same kind of thing occurring for multiple `GroupName`s and different `Id`s.

What I would like to get from this list is, **for any named group, each first changed value** - So the output for `Group1` would be:

```
Dt:             Id:        Val:
2016/01/01      1          Val1
2016/01/04      1          Val2
2016/01/05      1          Val3
2016/01/06      1          Val1
2016/01/08      1          Val4
```

In other words, for a given `GroupName`:

1. Group by Id
2. Order by Date
3. Select any item within each group where item[index] != item[index-1]

So, I got the following code working:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetUpdatedVals(List<MyClass> myVals, string groupName)
{
    var filteredVals = myVals.Where(v => v.GroupName == groupName).ToList();

    return filteredVals
        .OrderBy(v => v.Id)
        .ThenBy(v => v.Dt)
        .Where((v, idx) => idx == 0 || v.Id != filteredVals[idx - 1].Id || v.Val != filteredVals[idx - 1].Val)
        .Select(v => v);
}
```

But it seems like there should be a better way to do this via Linq using GroupBy or something not having to create a separate holding list.

Any ideas? Or is this a "perfectly good" / the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, @TimSchmelter, what I meant was that for each `GroupName` and `Id` combination you would see different values (not the same as these, though) appearing for different dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something a bit more elegant, you can use the GroupAdjacent by function described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4682163/6137718 :

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupAdjacentBy<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
    {
        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (e.MoveNext())
            {
                var list = new List<T> { e.Current };
                var pred = e.Current;
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (predicate(pred, e.Current))
                    {
                        list.Add(e.Current);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        yield return list;
                        list = new List<T> { e.Current };
                    }
                    pred = e.Current;
                }
                yield return list;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can use this to group all adjacent elements that have the same Val, after sorting by Id and Dt. Then from each group, we select the first one, as that represents the most recent change. The updated code would look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetUpdatedVals(List<MyClass> myVals, string groupName)
{
    return myVals
        .Where(v => v.GroupName == groupName)
        .OrderBy(v => v.Id)
        .ThenBy(v => v.Dt)
        .GroupAdjacentBy((x, y) => x.Val == y.Val && x.Id == y.Id)
        .Select(g => g.First());
}
```

Comment: But how do you include the `Id` groups. You only check the `Val`. OP's working approach checks both properties.

Comment: Thank you so much! - The GroupAdjacentBy is definitely pretty great to know exists and I'm going to add it to my extensions and use it in this case, but I'm also curious to know if there's any solution that doesn't require the additional list created too! But **thank you!**

Comment: @JohnBustos If you are referring to the list created in the Linq extension, I don't think it's avoidable. If you are referring to the list created to get the filtered vars, that is avoidable, I'll update my solution to account for that.

Comment: But it still doesn't track the ID-changes. Afaik every group-name can contain  multiple ID's.

Comment: Exactly, @TimSchmelter - But I did manage to make this work by changing the GroupAdjacentBy to `GroupAdjacentBy((x, y) => x.Id == y.Id & x.Val == y.Val)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter To make sure that adjacent items with same Val but not the same Id are not grouped, I added a condition.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your requirement and your working code correctly you want to get all changes. Since you already order by the ID you can use `GroupBy` to get the `ID`-Groups. Now you need to add all per ID-Group where the `Val`-value changes from one object to the other. You could use following single query which creates list of each group to access the previous element via index and `SelectMany` to flatten them.

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetUpdatedVals(List<MyClass> myVals, string groupName)
{
    return myVals
        .Where(v => v.GroupName == groupName)
        .OrderBy(v => v.Id)
        .ThenBy(v => v.Dt)
        .GroupBy(v => v.Id)
        .Select(g => g.ToList())
        .SelectMany(gList => gList
            .Where((v, idx) => idx == 0 || v.Val != gList[idx - 1].Val));
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Tim, this worked and, actually exactly answers the question I posed of how to do this via grouping, but the GroupAdjacentBy does seem to be a more elegant solution given this specific scenario. But, truly, **THANK YOU SO MUCH** for providing this... This is what I wanted to know how to do overall!!