# C# arrary group by continuous integers

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq-group

In C#,

Given the following array of integers e.g. 
100001
100002
100005
100006
100007
100009
100011

I want to produce a data structure holding the following values

```
[0] => {Type= "Continuous", Count=2, Items = [100001, 100002]}
[1] => {Type= "Continuous", Count=3, Items = [100005, 100006, 100007]}
[2] => {Type= "Individual", Count=2, Items = [100008, 100011]}
```

The data structure is not important. I am looking for an algorithm to group the integers in this way.

Comment: A simple loop might be the fastest and easiest way to achieve.

Comment: Probably a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681949/use-linq-to-group-a-sequence-of-numbers-with-no-gaps

Comment: @Rob Yes, It looks really similar, but it has a little difference.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your array of integers is sorted:

```
class MyGroup
{
   public string Type => (Numbers?.Count??0) == 1? "Individual" : "Continuous";
   public List<int> Numbers;
   public int Count => Numbers.Count;
}

List<MyGroup> LST = new List<MyGroup>();

List<int> Temp = new List<int>();

//Run from 0 to second-last element (arr is your array)
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
{
  Temp.Add(arr[i]); //add this number to current group's list
  if (arr[i + 1] != arr[i] + 1) //if next number is not adjacent
  {
    LST.Add(new MyGroup() { Numbers = Temp }); //create a new group
    Temp = new List<int>(); //and a new current list
  }
}

LST.Add(new MyGroup() { Numbers = Temp }); //create a new group

//The above loop exits before the last item of the array.
//Here we simply check if it is adjacent, we add it to the last group.
//otherwise we create a new group for it.
if (arr[arr.Length - 1] == arr[arr.Length - 2] + 1)
  LST.Last().Numbers.Add(arr.Last());
else
  LST.Add(new MyGroup() { Numbers = new List<int>(new[] { arr.Last() }) });
```

Comment: Is there a way to only group continuous elements if the continuous segment contains over N elements?

Comment: Yes. In the above code, inside the `for` loop's `if` condition, check if there are over N elements in `Temp`. If so, continue with the current code. Otherwise, run a nested loop within `else`, where u create individual groups for each element of `Temp`.

Comment: Slight mistake on my part. I thought you wanted to keep sparse items individual; i.e. one in each group. You'll need to do minor modification to group sparse items.

Comment: Yes I would like to group sparse items. That is my intention but I didn't specify this in my original question so my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
class Group
{
    public int StartIndex { get; set; }

    public int EndIndex { get; set; }

    public int Length { get { return EndIndex - StartIndex; } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{StartIndex}-{EndIndex}";
    }
}
```

Then

```
static List<Group> FindGroups(int[] intArray)
{
    List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
    int tempStartIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < intArray.Length; i++)
    {
        var value = intArray[i] - intArray[i - 1] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
        if (value == 1)
        {
            groups.Add(new Group() { StartIndex = tempStartIndex, EndIndex = i - 1 });

            tempStartIndex = i;
        }
    }
    if (groups[groups.Count - 1].EndIndex != intArray.Length)
    {
        groups.Add(new Group() { StartIndex = tempStartIndex, EndIndex = intArray.Length - 1 });
    }
    return groups;
}
```